# QT error with executing "make"

Tags: c++, qt

I am currently using QT creator 4.62. I created a widgets application and I did a test run. The output log displayed:

22:41:39: Could not determine which "make" command to run. Check the "make" step in the build configuration.

When I downloaded QT, I pre-installed minGW 5.30 in tools. I also checked Tools >> Options >> Build and run. It autodetected MinGW 5.3.0 for c++ which should work.

Here are some photos of my problem:

Compiler Setup

[image]

The problem

[image]

The kits tab:

[image]

Comment: show kits tab..

Comment: the problem according to the image that you uploaded is that the one that is by default Desktop (default) has problems, the solution is that you make the Desktop Qt 5.11.1 MinGW 32 bit do it by default with the button Make Default that is right to do this, select the item with the computer icon, then press the Make Default button and finally the Apply button that is in the lower right corner.